# HTML page loading a totally blank screen

Tags: html, django

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <title>Is it New Year's</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       {% if newyear %}
           <h1>YES</h1>
       {% else % }
           <h1>NO</h1>
       {% endif %}
   </body>
</html>
```

When I try running this HTML code I don't get an error but do get just a blank page when I should be getting either a yes or a no. Running this server using Django.

Comment: Can you share the related `urls.py` and `views.py`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem https://imgur.com/a/TxMaTwN posted here

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question